# How to access the iCloud Drive Archive folder on my MacBook?

Tags: macos, icloud

I couldn't find 'iCloud Archive' folder in the Finder. I have been searching it everywhere in the desktop to the different folders, but I couldn't find it. Where do I access it and its contents?

Answer (score 1):

If you signed out of iCloud and kept a local copy, you should have an Archive folder created in your Home folder:

> If you turn off iCloud Drive or sign out of iCloud, you have the option to keep a local copy of your files that are in iCloud Drive. Whether you decide to keep a local copy or not, a new Desktop and Documents folder is created in your home folder. **If you choose to keep a local copy, your files in iCloud Drive are copied to a folder called iCloud Drive (Archive) in your home folder.** Then you have the option to move any files that were in your iCloud Desktop and Documents, back to your new local Desktop and Documents.

([Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT206985))

There is a possibility that:

- You didn't keep a local copy
- You moved/deleted the folder
- You already emptied the contents of the folder

Answer (score -2):

I use a CleanMyMac app. Under Files (Left side, bottom) there’s a menu called Space Lens. I found my files easily there and moved them back to the desktop in no time.

I feel called to answer this because I was toying with Manage Storage on my MacBook Air and clicked Store in iCloud… Lo and Behold, my storage looked kinda the same but I’ve experienced insufficient disk space when I used this feature.
So, when I disabled this feature (Store in iCloud…), it says all files uploaded will be in iCloud drive (archive) but there was no way to find it easily.

I don’t work with CleanMyMac, I used to think they’re malware or what not. Try it, and trust it. I’ve been using it since 2013. Good luck travelers.

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly how this tool helps to find the Archive folder?